# Apache Common Utils package got changed to 4

Tags: java

We have used CollectionUtils.isEmpty is many places through out the application around 1000 files.

Now the package name has been changed in the recent version apachecommonutils to apache common utils4.

Do we need to have our own utility package and call inside the above API since the changes are drastic during upgrade. If we have our own utility the package name change would be in one single place.

What would be the best practice?

How does enterprise application builts it?

Comment: Most IDEs (e.g. IntelliJ) have powerful refactoring tools which can take this situation and make it much easier for you.  I vote for using the new JAR and just changing your code everywhere.

Comment: Depends on how many internal projects have to be rebuilt, regression tested and deployed... Especially since changes breaking name compatibility usually come with other breaking changes.  Do you have a good reason for wanting to upgrade Apache Common Utils?  If you need some new functionality you are stuck, if not you might want to wait and make a real plan for how you're going to implement this.

Comment: We are facing lot of merge issues and conflicts due to several people working and merging on different projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We are facing lot of merge issues and conflicts due to several people working and merging on different projects

There's really only one way to do this.

1. Go back to the prior version of Commons Utils for now;
2. Plan this upgrade as a separate, major project that can be done when your code base is in a stable state. Make a new feature branch, off of a release, and do nothing else on that branch EXCEPT the upgrade.
3. Make sure you thoroughly regression-test all the modules that use Common Utils and are affected by the upgrade